# Error uploading document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

When I upload a document to document library that has workflows the following error occurs.

> The file Minutes/By Quarter.dwp has been modified by
>   i:0#.w|xac0000\sp_admin on 04 Feb 2016 17:39:39 +0800.

File is added to the library but required fields that I tagged does not show up.

Comment: I think put a pause in the workflow for couple of seconds while uploading the docs...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2009/09/22/itemadded-event-on-document-library-the-file-has-been-modified-by-on-error.aspx